# php mysql - how query the database with multiple ids

Tags: php, mysqli

I am looking for the result of the queries contained in this table:
`

```
$queries = array_map(static function ($odd_task) use ($id_oeuvre): string{
    return <<<SQL
    SELECT 
        PK_ASSOC_OVRUSRTCH,
        FK_OUT_REF_USR
    FROM sc_t_assoc_ovr_usr_tch
    WHERE 
        FK_OUT_REF_TCH = {$odd_task}
    AND FK_OUT_REF_OVR = {$id_oeuvre};
    SQL;
    }, $odd_tasks);
```

`Basically, we should be able to make an array of these loops and get the results:`

```
$oRecordset = mysqli_query($queries[0], $oConnexion);
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_object($oRecordset)){
    $pk_usr_tch_missing1 = $fetch->PK_ASSOC_OVRUSRTCH;
    $user_missing1 = $fetch->FK_OUT_REF_USR;
}
$oRecordset = mysqli_query($queries[1], $oConnexion);
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_object($oRecordset)){
    $pk_usr_tch_missing2 = $fetch->PK_ASSOC_OVRUSRTCH;
    $user_missing2 = $fetch->FK_OUT_REF_USR;
}
```

`

I would like to iterate over that future table and get the results of the requests that are contained within it as strings.

Comment: you need one query with FK_OUT_REF_TCH IN (here go all ids from $odd_tasks)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I finally found the solution thanks to your suggestion.